# Use Roslyn with MVC5, Web API on .net 4.5.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, roslyn

I have a problem)

My invoriment is IIS 7.5, net. framework 4.5.1, asp.net (mvc5, web api)
I also want to use Roslyn (C# 6.0) in my project.

I add nuget packages:

```
1)Microsoft.Net.Compilers
2)Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
```

and then publish the solution. The publish is successed but unfortunately there's **compilation error**(**-2146232576**.) when i navigate to home page

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>c:\inetpub\wwwroot\raildebug\bin\roslyn\csc.exe /t:library /utf8output /nostdlib+ /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\08f265c3\0090845f_21aece01\Antlr3.Runtime.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\3b8f736d\0049e60f_963ad001\System.Web.Mvc.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\33f05b99\00288b1c_eaadd201\Microsoft.Owin.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\b9034878\5e979053_95ffd201\NaftanRailway.Domain.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\c1c460bf\00e3935e_963ad001\System.Web.WebPages.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\86b8c936\00cb2cb9_2898d201\log4net.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\b2f3290a\00e3935e_963ad001\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\2624aaf0\006465e4_f01ed201\WebActivatorEx.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\8e25d77d\00670c62_7a7cd201\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\8d8b0191\00f904a6_b254d001\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\e7908327\00ef0d00_674cd001\System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\87959831\00ef0d00_674cd001\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\3705bb6c\00f904a6_b254d001\EntityFramework.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\2d8cb9d4\00324c9b_2b48d001\Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\1376ef9d\007baf89_2118cf01\WebGrease.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\7e0e1c87\00b3475d_7a7cd201\System.Spatial.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\c044609d\00e470f1_396acd01\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\984c09d2\00504bbf_8ddbd001\System.Web.Http.OData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\7fb7c7ff\004733a2_21e8d201\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Abstractions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Abstractions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\5258270d\00e3d01c_3263cf01\Ninject.Web.Mvc.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\e0248369\00029e58_963ad001\WebMatrix.WebData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\4c12b836\0082ed1e_eaadd201\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\f3aa06d4\006b1190_64c4d201\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\25f24551\006e8a0c_1c27cf01\System.Web.Optimization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\5f151fc2\0065341e_963ad001\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\d71a79df\006ccff2_60f1d201\MoreLinq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\2744a885\00af1e20_eaadd201\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\d63f9296\00b25fd4_05d4cf01\Ninject.Web.Common.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Routing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Routing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\d930f608\00e3935e_963ad001\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\f02b3be9\00735b25_963ad001\System.Web.Http.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\e6a23017\00843e18_963ad001\System.Web.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\05cd7309\00cd1ea8_9eeed201\AutoMapper.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\a8bfcc9f\00cf956b_7a7cd201\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\c0faf46c\0092beb0_23a2d201\LinqKit.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\63247a23\00f2a493_64c4d201\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\45e3537b\0076d866_2b48d001\Ninject.Web.WebApi.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\171c0b6f\009b0422_6dc5d201\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\81703970\0040b24c_963ad001\WebMatrix.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\003345b8\00afd39c_77c1cd01\Owin.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\6590b598\a4fbc380_b4ffd201\NaftanRailway.WebUI.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\bdd7150c\00055a44_963ad001\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\6048de6c\7186de53_95ffd201\NaftanRailway.BLL.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\3b44a1dd\008b09ce_03e0d001\RestSharp.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\c8e4aa03\00358577_814ecf01\Ninject.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\assembly\dl3\742a007e\00e3935e_963ad001\System.Web.Helpers.dll" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\App_global.asax.lm_ad2tf.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /warnaserror- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\App_global.asax.lm_ad2tf.0.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0647f895\220a3803\App_global.asax.lm_ad2tf.1.cs"

ASP.NET :4.0.30319.18446
```

I would like to find out what's wrong? Does it have to be installed .net 4.6?

I've found some linked solution, but is there no other more elegant way to solve this problem?

[IIS Compilation Error -2146232576 AspNetInitializationExceptionModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892851/iis-compilation-error-2146232576-aspnetinitializationexceptionmodule)

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer to my question :)

- https://cpratt.co/using-csharp-6-or-7-with-mvc-5/

Related links:

- [What version of the compiler is in a microsoft.net.compilers package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583579/what-version-of-the-compiler-is-in-a-microsoft-net-compilers-package)
- [How to use roslyn c# compiler with visual studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138235/how-to-use-roslyn-c-sharp-compiler-with-visual-studio-2015)
- [Roslyn and .NET Runtime version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436260/roslyn-and-net-runtime-version)
- [Does C# 6.0 work for .NET 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921701/does-c-sharp-6-0-work-for-net-4-0?noredirect=1&lq=1)

***Practice Results:***
The ***Roslyn compiler*** is supported in diffrent .net versions, but

- Microsoft.Net.Compilers (< 2) supports minimum core c#6.0 syntax and needs >= .net 4.5
- Microsoft.Net.Compilers (>= 2) supports full c#6.0 and higher syntax, need at
  least .net 4.6